# Scala, create a form with more than 22 fields

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I'm using scala and Play framework and i want create a form with more than 22 fields so I share my field in 3 tuple like that:

```
val firstMapping = tuple(  
     "f1" -> text, "f2" -> text, ... "f18" -> text
)

val secondMapping = tuple(
    "f19" -> text, "20"-> text ... "f25" -> text
)

val thirdMapping = tuple(
   "f26" -> text, ... "f29" -> text
)
```

So after I regroup them in a form:

```
val createForm = From(tuple(
   "general" -> firstMapping,
   "specific" -> secondMapping,
   "more_specific" -> thirdMapping
))
```

I think this is the good solution, but my question is about the view file (i'm in a MVC architecture)

In that view I want to pass my form like that:

```
@(formCreate: Form[])
```

But I don't know what I need to put in the " [] " (I'm french I don't know wath is the word for that in english) and how to create my field in HTML ?

Usually I use that kind html form:

```
@helper.form() {
    <input type="text" name="id_metier" id="id_metier" maxlength="255"/>
}
```

So can I use that kind of field again or I need to use specific field from Play framework ? And what are the parameter for that `@(formCreate: Form[])` ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Your form is of type `Tuple3` with some other tuples inside. Painful to read, write, use, maintain.

```
Form[((String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), (String, String, String, String, String, String, String), (String, String, String, String))]
```

Refer to the docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms

and just create a `case class` that will contain 3 nested `case classes` for your data, name fields appropriately.

Here is the example from docs for nested `case class`

```
case class AddressData(street: String, city: String)
case class UserAddressData(name: String, address: AddressData)

val userFormNested: Form[UserAddressData] = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "address" -> mapping(
      "street" -> text,
      "city" -> text
    )(AddressData.apply)(AddressData.unapply)
  )(UserAddressData.apply)(UserAddressData.unapply)
)
```

When creating form you refer to nested fields with `.` notation

```
@helper.inputText(userFormNested("name"))
@helper.inputText(userFormNested("address.street"))
@helper.inputText(userFormNested("address.city"))
```

Comment: Yeah I have see the method that you say, but the application is special and use `case classes` it's not a good idea here because it's not also obvious like the exemple of the doc. Thank you for the good answer, I will use the painful method first and if it's too painful I will search tu use nested class

Comment: If you could elaborate more on why case classes aren't good here, what your use case is it would be easier to figure something out.

Comment: Because my case class haven't data like an adress which use the case class AdressDate, I don't know if you can understand what I want to say. I don't really can explain it in english

Comment: I am guessing you used nesting just to be able to fit in all your data into one form, and the structure is indeed flat. I am wondering what kind of data requres 29 indistinct fields. Note that you can create a `case class MyData(f1: String, f2: String, ..., f29: String)`. Or maybe use a list and assure its size somehow.

Comment: Okay so if I create a `case class MyDate` which contains all the fields I need, I will have:
`val formDate: Form[MyData] = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
     ...
  )(MyData.apply)(MyData.unapply)
)`

 for the HTML part how can I pass the Form ?

Comment: But if i want to use the tuple3, in my controller I have a function like that:
`createForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      hasErrors = { formWithErrors =>  
      println("in errors, why...") 
      Ok(views.html.index)},
      success = { value =>
             Entity.createFromForm(value
    }
  )
}`

But now with tuple3 it's not value, I try with `case f(irstMapping, secondMapping, thirdMapping)` 
 it compile but it not work, when I use the form it will not create the entity.

Comment: I don't understand ehat exact issue is here, can you edit your question with a simplified example that still has the problem you need solved and that one can put into project and test it and see how to fix?